# Hibernate Force Index

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

How can we use "**Force Index**" in HQL .

```sql
SELECT * FROM t1 
USE INDEX FOR Join (i1)
FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (i2);
```

I dont want to use sql query. I want to specify it using Hibernate criteria.
I already have indexes on the tables.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate supports sql query.You make *Force index* by using native sql query.With Hibernate Criteria it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own sql function http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/10/07/using-use-index-with-hibernatemysql/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34201709)